# Android wont scroll through txt file

Tags: android, scroll, android-xml

I have a helpdoc.txt file stored in res/raw within eclipse.  It displays inside my application by using the below code:

```
public class HelpPage extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help);
    //read in
    InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.helpdoc);
        try {
            TextView helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_HelpText);
            String strFile = inputStreamToString(iFile);
            helpText.setText(strFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //nothing here
        }
}//end onCreate

    /**
         * Converts an input stream to a string
            */
        public String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
            StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(is);
            String strLine = null;
            while ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuffer.append(strLine + "\n");
            }//end while
                dataIO.close();
                is.close();
                return sBuffer.toString();
        }//end method
```

It loads correctly, but does not all fit on the screen, when I try to scroll, I cannot read the rest of the text.

This is the related XML layout file for completeness: http://pastebin.com/PtskJbqt

Can anyone advise how I can scroll down to ensure the user can read the entire file?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you simply add a scrollview on top of the TextView. I think that's more easier.

Comment: @AndroSelva Hi Andro, how do you mean? Thanks.

Comment: also you can use `ScrollView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set:    `helpText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

Comment: This was perfect, thanks.  I have an older application that I borrowed code from - didn't need this before?  (The scrolling worked fine on the other app) Not sure why that is!  It works anyway, bit of a mystery about the older app though.

Answer (score 1):

Like this,

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">



<TextView
       android:id="@+id/TextView_HelpText"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:autoLink="all"
       android:isScrollContainer="true"
       android:textStyle="italic"
       android:drawablePadding="5px"
       android:textColorLink="@color/logo_color"
       android:linksClickable="true"
       android:fadingEdgeLength="25px"
       android:fadingEdge="vertical"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:padding="@dimen/help_text_padding"
       android:textSize="@dimen/help_text_size"
       android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
       android:bufferType="spannable"
        android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

</ScrollView>
```

And also using "px" is not recommended. use "dip" instead for fadingLength and padding.